# How to check if an object has been assigned to an integer variable

Tags: delphi, casting, variable-assignment

I'm assigning both objects and integer values to an integer variable:

```
MyIntegerValue := Integer(MyObject);
MyIntegerValue := 2;
MyIntegerValue := 500;
...
```

How to check if MyIntegerValue has been assigned with a valid object?

Comment: A [TValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue) can hold both integer types and class instances. There is no safe way to say that your integer is pointing to an instantiated class.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is **don't do that**, because it's foolish. Don't mix integers and objects, and you don't have that problem. Seriously, when you start having to ask questions like this, it's an extremely strong indication that you've done something totally wrong, and the best way to get out of that situation is to stop doing that thing you're doing so wrong that you had to ask this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to check if MyIntegerValue has been assigned with a valid object?

You can't.  There is no data bits to indicate what the `Integer` is holding.  A pointer (no matter what it is pointing at) is just a number as far as the CPU is concerned.  It just happens to be a number that represents a memory address.

Also, your attempt to store an object pointer in an `Integer` will not work on 64-bit systems, you would need to use `NativeInt`/`NativeUInt` instead, otherwise you will truncate the pointer value.

To do what you are asking, you would have to use another variable to indicate what the `Integer` value represents.  Or better, use a container type that knows what it is holding, like `TValue` or `Variant` (and yes, you can store object pointers in a `Variant`, with some work).

Answer (score 4):

You should attend to what been said about type safety and typecasts since the [very first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212703/how-to-check-if-an-object-has-been-assigned-to-an-integer-variable#comment58141535_35212703) to you question. I won't repeat that and focus on the practical approach to specific problem. This also constrains the discussion to 32bit target (as you question assumes `SizeOf(Integer) = SizeOf(Pointer)`);

First of all, since objects are pointers <sub>(as you learned from the other replies)</sub>, its platform-imposed properties could help to distinguish between real pointer (valid!) and integer value. Take a look how Windows tell **character pointer** and **enumerated** values apart:

```
function Is_IntResource(lpszType: PChar): BOOL;
begin
  Result := ULONG_PTR(lpszType) shr 16 = 0;
end;
```

This exploits the fact what no user-mode data can be allocated at that low memory region on 32-bit Windows platform and thus, no valid pointer value `p < 65536` can exist.

Next, you can use Delphi-specific internal data format of object instances, to check if pointer is really an object instance:

```
/// <summary>
///   Verifies that the argument points to valid object instance.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="EAccessViolation">
///   If segmentation fault occurs while attempting to read VMT and/or its
///   field from the specified memory address.
/// </exception>
/// <remarks>
///   Delphi only, incompatible with FPC.
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
///   <code lang="Delphi">
///     procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
///     begin
///       ShowMessage(BoolToStr(IsInstance(Self), True));
///     end;
/// </code>
/// </example>
function IsInstance(Data: Pointer): Boolean;
var
  VMT: Pointer;
begin
  VMT := PPointer(Data)^;
  Result := PPointer(PByte(VMT) + vmtSelfPtr)^ = VMT;
end;
```

This function examines **V**irtual **M**ethod **T**able for signature of Delphi RTL and (given memory reads operations were successful and signature check passed) identifies arbitrary pointer as `TObject` (or descendant) instance.

`nil`/`0`: You need to take a even more special precautions about `0` pointer values, since it is pretty meaningful as `Pointer` and also common as `Integer`.

Comment: Also, IIRC 32bit Windows also has reserved memory region at the top of address space, meaning what small negative values can be recognized as well.

Comment: +1 [Internal Data Formats (Delphi) - Class Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Class_Types) for the VMT reference - see the `vmtSelfPtr` constant

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it reliably, and you shouldnt try to outsmart the type safety in Delphi.

---

To clarify: With reliably I mean the following scenarios:

You assign an **integer** to the variable. Then, later you come back and want to determine whether it is an integer or an object reference. You may be tempted to first check whether it is an object reference by investigating the memory block pointed at. You might see structures and data as `Free Consulting` showed. Ahaa, you think, I have stored an object reference! However, you actually did store an integer, its value just happens to coincide with the address of an object.

and

You assign a valid **object** reference, later the object is freed and the memory is reused for whatever. Your check for an object like memory structure fails and you draw the wrong conclusion that you have stored an integer.